# Beamer: Change color of items

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm customising a Beamer theme for my own needs and I am wondering how I can efficiently work with parent templates. For example, I want to modify the color of all items (enumerate, itemize, table of content) to blue. I tried several things like

```
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{bg=deepBlue}
```

or

```
\setbeamercolor{item}{bg=deepBlue}
```

but none of the above works. Am I missing some parent template or logical structure?

It might intersect with a color scheme I use. A mini example is below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent} % makes things that appear later transparent
  \usecolortheme{seagull} %gray and naughty
}

\definecolor{deepBlue}{HTML}{000066}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=deepBlue}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item check
\item check
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `fg`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{ fg=red}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

Refer to `beameruserguide` to learn more about the coloring scheme in beamer.

**Update** after the MWE we see that you want the following:

**Update 2** According to the comment one wants subitems too:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}

\usecolortheme{seagull} %gray and naughty


\definecolor{deepBlue}{HTML}{000066}

\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=deepBlue}
\usesubitemizeitemtemplate{%
    \tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\color{deepBlue}$\blacktriangleright$}%
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item check
\begin{itemize}
\item check
\item check
\end{itemize}
\item check
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`item projected`is a special version for setting colors with circles and numbers or balls. In that case you need `bg` again.   See `beameruserguide`. 
Since `Boadilla` defines the subitems with some hard-coding we need to do alike. `\usesubitemizeitemtemplate` will force subitems to be as it's argument. Imo this is not quite a good coding style, since users have to look it up in the source.

Comment: sorry, I just added a mini example. Unfortunately, your mini example works, but not in my example.

Comment: Your solution works fine. But now, I have subitems, these are triangles by default, and I can't manage to get them to be deepBlue too. I tried "subitem projected" "item" "itemize item" "itemize subitem" "subitem", but none of them affected this black triangle.

Comment: Also instead can we change the numbers' color inside the bullet?